# What resolution (in pixels) should videos taken in the new iPad (3rd generation) be?

Tags: video, camera, ipad

After recording a video in the "new" iPad, and transferring it to PC (via email or Dropbox), the resolution is 568 x 320.

Images are 2592 x 1936.

I can't find any information about what resolution to expect, except that it should be 1080p, but I don't really know what that means.

When filming, the picture is zoomed in compared to when taking a photo.  I can't find a way to zoom out.

Is this resolution normal?

Comment: Email (and I guess dropbox) compress the video to a .mov file about a fraction of the size.

I was able to view the images and videos by directly connecting the iPad to the pc, and mounting it as a drive.

The actual dimensions of the video appear to be 1920 x 1088.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Email (and I guess dropbox) compresses the video to a .mov file about a fraction of the size.

I was able to view the images and videos by directly connecting the iPad to the PC and mounting it as a drive.

The actual dimensions of the video appear to be 1920 x 1088.